# Multinomial Naive Bayes on Python (Class Frequency Prior)

Tags: python, naivebayes

I want to perform a Multinomial Naive Bayes on Python by using the Class Frequency for my prior.

```
mnb = MultinomialNB(alpha = 1.0, class_prior = None, fit_prior = True)
mnb_pred = mnb.fit(X_train, np.ravel(Y_train)).predict(X_full)
```

In the code above, how can I specify that I want to use the class frequency prior for my MultinomialNB?
I suppose I will have to adjust the parameters `class_prior` and `fit_prior` somehow, but I am not sure how exactly I should do this.

Thank you!